# Life is mysterious to take too serious/seriously?

Tags: grammaticality

Life is mysterious to take too serious/seriously?
Which one is correct?

Comment: See also [“Too serious” vs “too seriously”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/27449)

Comment: Neither.  Semantically they don't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

The word serious is an **adjective** that is used to describe someone or a situation.

The word **seriously** is an adverb and in this case it acts like an adverb to say **how** life should be viewed (not too seriously because it is mysterious)

Also, the sentence might sound a bit better if you say it this way:
**Life is too mysterious to be taken seriously**.
I hope that helps.